# How to pass value in URL using codeigniter and $_GET it in a public function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do you add value in URL using codeigniter and $_GET it in a public function?
So this is the button directed to the controller public function

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>asset_management/editpc?$comp_id=<?php echo $comp_id?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

and this is what the public function in the controller looks like:

```
public function edit_pc(){
           if(isset($_GET['comp_id'])){
           $comp_id=$_GET['comp_id'];
           }
           $this->load->view('getcomp',$comp_id);

       }
```

is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the it in codeigniter way

`<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset_management/editpc/<?php echo  $name; ?>/<?php echo $value; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a`>

$name is the label you want to pass (company_id) and $value is the value of label ( company_id value ) once outputted the above like will look like the following

`<a href="http://yoursite.com/asset_management/editpc/company_id/5" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a`>

now change your function

```
public function edit_pc($name='',$value='')
{
   $data[$name]= $value;
   $this->load->view('getcomp',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your URI segments as parameters to the base_url() call and - *emphasized text*as suggested in another answer on this page - use the Codeigniter way for URLs: 
*controller/method/parameter*. If `$comp_id = 4;` then this line

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url("asset_management/editpc/$comp_id"); ?>'
    class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

would produce a link to `http://example.com/asset_management/editpc/4`

The controller's function then becomes

```
//function takes an argument which comes from the last segment of the URL
public function edit_pc($comp_id)
{
  //create an array to pass variables to the the view 
  $data['comp_id'] = $comp_id;

   $this->load->view('getcomp',$data);
   }
```

The view will use the var `$comp_id`. If we had used `$data['some_other_name']` then the view should look for and use `$some_other_name`

Comment: i have an error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception()...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code here, what specifically are you asking about? Are you receiving any errors?

You should end your lines with ; in php:

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

&

```
<?php echo $comp_id; ?>
```

Also your URL structure doesn't appear to be correct, unless "editpc" is a file directory and the index.php there is set to call the edit_pc() function.

Comment: editpc is a public function in cmms2/asset_management/editpc
like this

Comment: Sure. Let's start with error messages, what are you getting?

Comment: Does your getcomp class extend the CI_Controller?

Comment: its not a class its a public function under a class extended to CI_Controller

Comment: That's your problem then, you can't pass an object to a function through a view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101237/discussion-between-treblaluch-and-bryanx).